# Jenkinsfile python argument

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I got a python script that I run like python3 test.py arg1 arg2

I setup a jenkins task and parametized it with 2 string parameters

how do I setup my Jenkinsfile? This is all I have right now

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('version') {
      steps {
        sh 'python3 --version'
      }
    }
    stage('hello') {
      steps {
        sh 'python3 temp.py'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like below?

```
pipeline {
  agent any
    parameters { 
        string(name: 'param1', defaultValue: 'test', description: '') 
        string(name: 'param2', defaultValue: 'test2', description: '')     
    }
  stages {
    stage('version') {
      steps {
        sh 'python3 --version'
      }
    }
    stage('hello') {
      steps {
        sh "python3 temp.py ${params.param1} ${params.param2}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes that worked. Thank you. What do i do if I have 100 items to enter for param1?

Comment: I mean param1 has 100 items and not just a single parameter

Comment: maybe I need a multi line parameter in jenkins?

Comment: @er24rf4f that depends on how you want to receive inputs. You can even pass all the args in a single parameter separated by a space.

Comment: i tried to use multiline string parameter but it dont recognize what i pass as parameter